# Intercepting backend 301/302 redirects (proxy_pass) and rewriting to another location block possible?

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-302

We have a couple of backends sitting behind our nginx front ends.

Is it possible to intercept 301 / 302 redirects sent by these backends and have nginx handle them?

We were thinging something alone the lines of:

```
error_page 302 = @target;
```

But I doubt 301/302 redirects can be handled the same as 404's etc etc... I mean, error_page probably doesnt apply to 200, etc error codes?

So to summarize:

Our backends send back 301/302s once in a while. We would like to have nginx intercept these, and rewrite them to another location block, where we could do any number of other things with them.

Possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You could use `proxy_redirect` directive ([documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)).

Nginx will still return 301/302 to the client but `proxy_redirect` will modify `Location` header and the client should make a new request to the URL given in the `Location` header.

Something like this should make the subsequent request back to nginx:

```
proxy_redirect    http://upstream:port/    http://$http_host/;
```

Answer (score 14):

I succeeded in solving a more generic case when a redirect location can be any external URL.

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        # You may need to uncomment the following line if your redirects are relative, e.g. /foo/bar
        #proxy_redirect / /;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
    }

    location @handle_redirects {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }
}
```

Alternative approach, which is closer to what you describe, is covered in ServerFault answer to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/641070/nginx-302-redirect-resolve-internally

Answer (score 11):

If you need to follow multiple redirects, modify Vlad's solution as follows:

1. Add

   ```
   recursive_error_pages on;
   ```

   to `location /`.
2. Add

   ```
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
   ```

   to the `location @handle_redirects` section.

Answer (score 8):

More on `proxy_redirect`, for relative locations

### Case

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://${API_HOST}:${API_PORT}/;
}
```

- the backend redirects to a relative location, which misses the `/api/` prefix
- the browser follows the redirection and hits a wall of incomprehension

### Solution

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://${API_HOST}:${API_PORT}/;
  proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) http://$http_host/api/$1;
}
```

Comment: Use `$scheme://` instead of http:// in the proxy redirect to get it to work on https.