# Rewrite proxy redirection with Nginx

Tags: perl, nginx, proxy, lua

Using Nginx to proxy Hadoop services web UI:

User --> (https) Nginx --> Hadoop {DATA NODES YARN web UI, webhdfs ...}

When I curl to `https://HOST/webhdfs/.....` the webhdfs server redirect to data node:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Location: http://DATA-NODE-1:50075/webhdfs ...
```

Where `DATA-NODE-1` is a DNS/IP "intern" to Hadoop cluster so end-user cannot access it.

I want to rewrite the `Location`header sent by proxied backend to:

`https://50075.DATA-NODE-1.HOST/webhdfs...` (PORT.SERVICE.HOST)

So Nginx can handle it, and do the proxy stuff.

Is it possible with Nginx modules or do I need a LUA/Perl script?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254456/intercepting-backend-301-302-redirects-proxy-pass-and-rewriting-to-another-loc

Comment: thanks, should do the trick!

Comment: @ThomasDecaux, could you please post your solution? I'm facing a similar issues.